# XML-based Spring MVC argument resolver

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm trying to migrate a big web app from Spring 2.5 to Spring 4. The whole context and MVCs are being configured using XML files, not annotated. Does anybody know if it's possible to declare argument resolvers to MVC beans injected using XML files? When using annotated controllers, the solution is to inject argument resolvers:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
  <mvc:argument-resolvers>
    <bean class="com.company.CustomResolver" />   
  </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

But I can't implement this solution because, due to size and legacy reasons, I can't migrate the app whole set of MVCs to annotated controllers.